# Vocabulary List From word2vec and GloVe

Tags: computational-linguistics

Is there a way I can access just the vocabulary list of pre-trained vectors for word2vec and GloVe? I do not need the entire n-dimensional embeddings.

Answer (score 3):

For the word2vec models, you probably can load them with the `gensim` package and access the vocabulary using `wv.vocab` property.
Like this:

```
from gensim.models.keyedvectors import KeyedVectors

model = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(filename, binary=True)
words = model.wv.vocab
```

where `filename` is the path to the pretrained model.
`binary` should be False if the pretrained model is in a text representation.